# The xml: Namespace

Tags: xhtml, xml-namespaces

What are the implications of using the `xml:` namespace? I'm talking about the difference between `xml:lang` and `lang`, and also `xml:id` and `id`. Should I prefer using `xml:` when writing XHTML documents? How compatible is it?

Comment: Please note that `xml:` is not a namespace but the prefix of a predefined namespace declaration that binds `xml` and the namespace name `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The W3C spec says to use both variants for XHTML documents, noting that the `xml:` prefixed one will take precedence.

For xml:lang and lang in particular read this one line text:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_7